# Google ReCaptcha in JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, recaptcha

**Hello,**

*Information, that may be handy: I am using NetBeans 8.2.*

A brief overview of my problem: I have a JFrame window in which I want to display a login form and a Google `No Captcha ReCaptcha` (the v2 version with the tickbox). I have tried using a `JEditorPane` but it did not work. [Here is how it looked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5oHx.png) In case You are wondering, in the picture the page http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo is being displayed (yes, with `http` because from what I know it does not support `https`).

This is how the code for it looks:

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
            jep.setEditable(false);   

    try {
      jep.setPage("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo");
    }catch (IOException e) {
      jep.setContentType("text/html");
      jep.setText("<html>Could not load</html>");
    } 

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

**Note:** the variable frame is a JFrame.

I really do not want to redirect the user to a browser window just to let them complete the captcha. But what options are there...?

**Thank You in advance**

Comment: From memory, `JEditorPane` doesn't support JavaScript

Comment: Ok, thank You.... but do You think there are other alternatives for ReCaptcha in JFrame?

Comment: You could consider using JavaFX's WebView, but I had some issues with it displaying text, but I was using example code so I might have something to do with the way I setup the test

Comment: Thank You! It works. But is there a way I can access the captcha using my Java code? I mean, I need to get the captcha answer code to send to the server for verification